# html putting text to a canvas

Tags: javascript, css, html, canvas

HTML:

```
   <div>
   <canvas id="text_box"  class="textbox" >
   </canvas>
   </div>
```

CSS:

```
    .textbox{
        position:absolute;
        background: black;
        left:100px;
        width:750px;
        height:100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        border:0;
        opacity:0.9;
        display:none;
    }
```

JavaScript

```
function drawCanvas() {
  var canvas = document.getElementById("text_box");
  var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

  context.lineWidth=1;
  context.fillRect(0,0,150,150);
  context.fillStyle="white";
  context.lineStyle="#ffff00";
  context.font="12px sans-serif";
  context.fillText("testestestsetestsetsetsetset.", 20, 20);
  context.rect(0,0,400,400);
  alert("test");
}
```

When I open this html, the text "test test test test test test test test test" just exceeds the width of the canvas, so the rest of it does not appear. i want the canvas(rectangle) to have a scroll bar if the text's length is long so i can scroll down to see the whole text.

I just started so I am not that familiar with the layout(css) part. can somebody give me some advice?

Comment: canvas does not have scroll bars (unless you program some). You need to be aware of your canvas dimensions and design/draw accordingly. Look into [measureText](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Drawing_text#Advanced_text_measurements) to help determining the width that your text will be and then handle.

Comment: Writing on a 2D context is quite different from writing text in an HTML element like a DIV. Basicallly, you're responsible for everything: if you write too much text for the canvas size (width) it will stop at the right edge.

Comment: Reference : http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/fTQkx/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a small div containing a larger canvas to have that div act as a "viewport" with scrollbars into the larger canvas.

HTML:

```
<div id=viewport>
    <canvas id="canvas" width=750 height=300></canvas>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#canvas{border:1px solid red;}
#viewport{
    overflow:scroll;
    width:200px; height:200px;
    border:2px solid blue;
}
```

Here's example code and a Demo:

```js
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var context=canvas.getContext("2d");

context.strokeStyle="#ffff00";
context.font="24px verdana";
context.fillText("This is some long text that will require scrolling to read.", 20, 50);
```

```css
body{ background-color: ivory; padding:10px; }
#canvas{border:1px solid red;}
#viewport{
  overflow:scroll;
  width:200px; height:100px;
  border:2px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div id=viewport>
  <canvas id="canvas" width=750 height=150></canvas>
</div>
```

BTW, you have some syntax errors in the context styling commands you've used. Here's a nice cheatsheet of all the valid canvas methods and properties: https://simon.html5.org/dump/html5-canvas-cheat-sheet.html

Comment: Thank you i was actually searching for some methods of how to put a kindof textbox into the web. and i think i can use this method. thanks a lot. i was searching this method for hours! have a nice day~